# textarea does not update after typing in it

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having an issue where the textarea does not update as expected. Here is a screenshot of my webapp:

[image]

When I click on any of the buttons "EN", "ZH", "JP", or "HI" then the Query URL box will update with the predefined url as expected. The issue happens when I type anything inside the textarea, then the buttons stop working. This only happens when I type with keyboard and does not happen when I only click on the textarea.

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
<label class="ng-label">Examples:</label>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div (click)="onClickPreDefine(0)" class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">EN</button>
    </div>
    <div (click)="onClickPreDefine(1)" class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">ZH</button>
    </div>
    <div (click)="onClickPreDefine(2)" class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">JP</button>
    </div>
    <div (click)="onClickPreDefine(3)" class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">HI</button>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<label class="ng-label">Query URL:</label>
<textarea (keyup)="onKeyQuery($event)" class="form-control" fullWidth rows="5" placeholder="The Url from which you want to fetch the semantic document.">{{query}}</textarea>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

// declare var $ : any

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic {
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-models-sd',
  templateUrl: './sd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sd.component.scss'],
})

export class SDComponent implements OnInit {
  msgs;

  // clickMessage = '';
  // text1 = '';
  query = '';
  res = '';

  treeview: any[];
  words: any[];
  sentences: any[];
  lists: any[];
  tables: any[];

  predefine_list = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft", "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%AE%E8%BD%AF", "https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88", "https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%89%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F"];

  overview = require('raw-loader!./markdown/overview.md').default;
  format = require('raw-loader!./markdown/format.md').default;
  annotations = require('raw-loader!./markdown/annotations.md').default;
  example = require('raw-loader!./markdown/example.md').default;
  metrics = require('raw-loader!./markdown/metrics.md').default;
  // get_access = require('raw-loader!./markdown/get_access.md').default;
  sample_code = require('raw-loader!./markdown/sample_code.md').default;
  production_scenario = require('raw-loader!./markdown/production_scenario.md').default;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // this.msgs = [{"name": "Root",
    //               "children": [
    //                 {"name": "plaintext", "text":"wowtext"},
    //                 {"name": "haha", "children": [{"name": "plaintext", "text": "hahatext"}]}
    //               ]}]
    this.msgs = [{
      name: "Root", key: 0, children: [
        { name: "DocumentTitle", key: 1, children: [{ name: "plaintext", key: 4, contents: [], text: "Dog Breeds - Types Of Dogs - American Kennel Club\n", "path": "", "children": [] }] },
        { name: "Main", key: 2, children: [{ name: "plaintext", key: 5, text: "maintext" }] },
        { name: "plaintext", key: 3, text: "wwwwtext" }
      ]
    }]
    this.words = [];
    this.sentences = [];
    this.treeview = [];
    this.lists = [];
    this.tables = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onKeyQuery(event: KeyboardEvent) { // with type info
    this.query = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }

  onClickPreDefine(id) {
    var that = this;
    that.query = that.predefine_list[id];
    // that.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  onClickMe() {
    // this.clickMessage = this.text1;
    if (this.query == "") {
        alert("Query URL cannot be empty!!!");
    }
    else {
    var json_data = {"url": this.query};
    var data2 = JSON.stringify(json_data);
    let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    };

    var that = this;
    this.http
      .post('/sd_api', data2, options)
      .subscribe(response => {
        that.res = JSON.parse(response['result']);

        that.treeview = [that.res['Annotations']];
        that.sentences[0] = that.res['WordsSentences']['Sentences'];
        that.words[0] = that.res['WordsSentences']['Words'];
        that.lists[0] = that.res["Lists"];
        that.tables[0] = that.res["Tables"];

        if (that.treeview[0] == null)
        {
            alert("Query URL is not yet supported. Please input something else.");
        }

        that.ref.detectChanges();
      });

  }

      that.ref.detectChanges();
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-models-sd-treeview',
  styleUrls: ['./sd.component.scss'],
  template: `
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" *ngFor="let node of messages">

    <ngb-panel *ngIf="node.name != 'plaintext'" [title]="'>> ' + node.name + ' <<'">


      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>

        <div *ngIf="node.children">
          <div *ngFor="let blockDict of node.children">
            <br *ngIf="blockDict.name == 'plaintext'">
              <app-models-sd-treeview [messages]="[blockDict]" *ngIf="[blockDict]"></app-models-sd-treeview>
              <span style="margin-left: 25px; display: block" *ngIf="blockDict.name == 'plaintext'">{{blockDict.text}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <code *ngIf="node.path"><small>{{ node.path }}</small></code>
      </ng-template>

    </ngb-panel>


  </ngb-accordion>
  `
})
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() messages;
  // displayedRows$: Observable<any>;  // don't use it if you don't know about it

  constructor() { };

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: There's no jquery code here, just JavaScript and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the textarea in a native way, try using `ngModel` of angular.

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]='query' class="form-control" fullWidth rows="5" placeholder="The Url from which you want to fetch the semantic document." />
```

With this you don't even need your `onKeyQuery` event. Since you're anyway using that to just set the value into `query` varibale ngModel will help as needed.